# Question about simplifying line integrals (line integrals of grad, div and curl)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

Consider vector fields v(x) and w(x), where
$v(x) = ∇φ(x)$
and
$w(x) =(
(1 − x^
2 − z^
2
) arcsin y,  (1 − x^
2 − z^
2
)arctanh(x
2
),  x)
$.

Here, $φ(x) = e^
{|x|^
2}$ 
and $x = (x, y, z)$.

If $Γ1$ and $Γ2$ are curves described by $x =
(cos θ, e− cos2 θ
,sin θ)$, find the values of

(a) (i) $\int_
{Γ1}
(3v + w) · dx$, where $0 \leq θ < 2π$.

(ii) $\int_{
Γ2}
(∇ ∧ v) · dx$, where $0 \leq θ < π$

(iii) The line integral $\int_{
Γ2}
∇ · [∇ ∧ (|v|
^2w)]ds$, where $0 \leq θ < π$

So these seem like pretty nasty line integrals so I thought that there must be 'tricks' for each of these that would simplify the matter. For the first path integral I realised that, as $\textbf{v}$ is a conservative field, the integral over the closed path of this vanishes. Then in this case, the x and y components of $\textbf{w}$ vanish so the first case simplifies quite nicely 9I get $\pi$ as the final result)

For the second part, since $\textbf{v}$ is conservative its curl is zero, and therefore the answer is zero.

Now I am stuck on the last part. I cannot see how to simplify it at all. I could put in that the x and y components of w are zero, but then I am still stuck. I do not know how to deal with the divergence of a fucntion in x,y and z multiplied by a vector...

Comment: A conservative field has zero curl, not necessarily zero divergence.

Comment: @Paul Thank you for pointing this out- I meant curl! I will correct it in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's zero too. The divergence of the curl of any vector field [is always zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Divergence_of_the_curl).